# SQL Statement to Select Day Interval

Tags: sql-server, datediff, getdate, dateadd

How can I get the range between a day dynamically for e.g. BETWEEN 23.05.2012 00:00  AND 23.05.2012 23:59 using MSSQL ? 
I got the first part;

```
WHERE
AND s.SCHEDULE_START_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 0, getdate()), 0) AND FILL HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to try something like

```
s.SCHEDULE_START_DATE >= dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 0, getdate()), 0)
AND s.SCHEDULE_START_DATE < (dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 0, getdate()), 0) + 1)
```

Have a look at the below example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4199)

Comment: I've decided to use the answer from astander; it was better performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE
(
    SCHEDULE_START_DATE DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Dates 
VALUES 
    ('20130522'),
    ('20130523'),
    ('20130524'),
    ('20130523 18:00:00'),
    ('20130523 23:59:59')

DECLARE 
      @DateFrom DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , @DateTo DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, 86399, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT *
FROM @Dates
WHERE SCHEDULE_START_DATE BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

**Output:**

```
SCHEDULE_START_DATE
-----------------------
2013-05-23 00:00:00.000
2013-05-23 18:00:00.000
2013-05-23 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: This statement will include 24 May 2013 too..., that is why you cannot use BETWEEN for this.